# Custom dataset object not setting chart.js bar chart colors in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I took a slightly different approach while creating the chart object. I created different objects for the different chart features and used data binding. I was able to complete each section of the chart except the bar colors. It is a stacked bar chart. I may need to take a different approach but I was hoping someone could tell me why it does not work. I will include a mock-up in Html and Typescript along with my custom object. As a note, I have tried different colors and such, I changed it to one value to expedite testing it. What I'm trying to say is that this stacked bar chart should look like a normal bar chart but I will have multiple bar colors later when the colors for each status are defined for my project. I apologize if that last part is confusing but each TrendResult object has the same backgroundColor on the code below but will be dynamic in the future.

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="!isExpanded">
  <div class="trend-chart-container-collapsed">
    <canvas
      baseChart
      [datasets]="chartData"
      [labels]="chartLabels"
      [chartType]="chartType"
      [options]="chartOptions"
      (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
      (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"
    ></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component Typescript:

```
 trendData: TrendData;
  testResults: TestResult[];
  isExpanded = false;

  public chartLabels: string[] = [];
  public chartData: VerificationTestTrendResult[] = [];
  public chartType = 'bar';
  public chartOptions: any = {
    'responsive': true,
    'maintainAspectRatio': true,
    'align': center,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]

    }
  };

loadCard(): void {
    console.log('Creating trend card component.');
    this.trendData = this.myService.getTrendData();
    this.testResults = this.myService.getTestResultData();
    const testStatuses = new Array();
    const designList = new Array();

    this.testResults.forEach(testResult => {
      if (!testStatuses.includes(testResult.testResult.toString())) {
        testStatuses.push(testResult.testResult.toString());
      }

      if (!designList.includes(testResult.Name)) {
        designList.push(testResult.Name);
        this.chartLabels.push(testResult.Name);
      }
    });

  testStatuses.forEach(testStatus => {
      const chartDataGroup = new TrendResult(testStatus, '#FF6384');
      designList.forEach(chartLabel => {
        const statusCount = this.testResults.filter(testResult =>
          testResult.Name.toString() === chartLabel && testResult.testResult === testStatus
        ).length;

        console.log('Adding result ' + chartLabel + ' for design ' + testStatus + ' at a count of ' + statusCount.toString());

        chartDataGroup.addResult(statusCount);

      });

      console.log('Adding chart data group: ' + chartDataGroup.toString());
      this.chartData.push(chartDataGroup);
    });
```

Typescript object

```
export class TrendResult {
  label: string;
  backgroundColor: string;
  data: number[] = [];

  constructor(design: string, backgroundColor: string) {
    this.label = design;
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor || 'rgba(0, 99, 132, 0.2)';
  }

  addResult(data: number): void {
    this.data.push(data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It was solved by using the HTML chart attribute "colors." I thought it could be apart of the data, but I guess not.